# Deleting Influential Points Leading to Non-constant Variance

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation, outliers, heteroscedasticity, leverage

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine+Quality
Using this data set, I am regressing chlorides on ten predictors (all except quality). After Box-Cox transforming chlorides, I get the following Q-Q plot and influential diagnostic plots:
[image]

[image]

As you can see, the points 837 and 838 are very influential, and so I decided to delete them and see what happens. Surprisingly, after deleting them, my model rejected the null hypothesis that the model has constant variance (p-value of almost 0) although it failed to reject the null hypothesis before deleting the points. Thus, should I keep the points?

Answer (score 0):

If those two points are very influential, it means they are **very informative**. It seems strange to want to delete informative data! Anyhow, such a decision should not be taken on the basis of secondary criteria like constant variance or not.

The reason it is a good idea to check on influential data points, is to check **if they are correct**. If they are correct, should definitely be kept. If they are (or could be erroneous), maybe delete them. But never make such decision on the basis of secondary criteria like you mention.